# Get number of not null bytes fread()

Tags: c, fread

I am developing simple server-client app and now I have problem with reading file on server side. Here is code:

```
int size; 
for (i = 0; i < parts; i++) {
    size = fread(buffer, 1, 256, file);
    printf("size: %i \n", size);
    send(sockfd, buffer, size, 0);
    /* ... */
}
```

I supposed that if `fread()` can read only (for example) 50 bytes, then size will be 50, but it's not true. It's still 256.
Is there any simple way how to get number of not null bytes?

Comment: `fread` does indeed return the number of items (not bytes, generally) that it read. It doesn't care about the *value* of those bytes, of course.

Comment: When it's pointer near end of the file (less than 256 bytes), why it "reads" bytes that aren't in that file? And read them as null bytes and returns 256? I thought it works that way...

Comment: It doesn't do that. You must have an error elsewhere. `fread` does what it should.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the length of the `buffer` after `fread()`, why don't use `strlen()`?

Also, its probably not a good idea to depend on the return value of `fread()` for number of bytes read. In case, if the `size` (second argement) is not `1`, it may cause you trouble with `actual` bytes count.

Comment: I need to read binary files so I think I can't use `strlen()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - he can't use strlen() because strlen() will not work.  strlen() causes so many problems in file/network code that it's actually legendary.

Comment: @SouravGhosh He can't use strlen() because he's reading binary, so the returned data might, e.g., look like this: "abcd\0efgh\0zzz". strlen() would then claim the data was 4 bytes long, when in fact much more was read. Also, the binary data might not even contain any null bytes, in which case strlen might access data past the end of the array.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks sir for updating me. I din't know that. Deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @RonBurk Thank you sir for the example. It's clear to me now. I wish I cloud upvote comments!!!

Comment: I know `fread()` format... I can't use `strlen()` because when I send jpg file then lots of bytes are missing and it's corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

`size_t fread(void * ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE * stream)` returns the number of elements successfully read.   In OP's case, a return value of 256 means 256 `char` are read.

A simple way to get number of "not null bytes" would entail a simple loop.

```
size_t size = fread(buffer, 1, 256, file);
size_t count = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i< size; i++) {
  if (buffer[i] == '\0') count++;
}
number_of_not_null_bytes = count;
```

As @Ron Burk says, the `\0` may be interspersed in `buffer` and need select handling before passing on to `send()`.